# Does boto3 have a StartChildWorkflowExecution decision?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-swf

Boto3 has a StartWorkflowExecution action but they talk of a StartChildWorkflowExecution decision but I cannot figure out how to create it. Any suggestions?

I cannot figure this out from this documentation: [A low-level client representing Amazon Simple Workflow Service (SWF)](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/swf.html?highlight=swf)

Answer (score 0):

The [Sub Workflows](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/swf_tut.html#sub-workflows) section of the [Amazon Simple Workflow Tutorial](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/swf_tut.html) contains an example.

Comment: I am aware of this, but it uses boto2, using a mix of the two versions seems bad... Is there no way to do this using boto3 options only?

Answer (score 0):

I think (haven't tried this yet), but reading the API it looks like you should be able to respond to a decision task with a decisionType of 'StartChildWorkflowExecution'.

So in which case you'd have something like this in your Decider:

```
response = client.respond_decision_task_completed(
    taskToken='string',
    decisions=[
        {
            'decisionType': 'StartChildWorkflowExecution',
```